# Can I really initialize an array with round brackets?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

Occasionaly, I've made a typo in one place of code of my program:

```
int a = 10;  
char* b = new char(a);
```

Error is obvious: I've written () instead of []. The strange thing is... code compiled ok, it ran in debugger ok. But compiled .exe outside of debugger crashed a moment after function with these lines was executed.

Is second line of code really legitimate? And if it is, what does it mean to compiler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a single char with the numerical value of `a`, in this case `10`. Pointers don't only point to arrays, y'know.

Answer (score 5):

You're allocating a *single* `char` and assigning it a value from `a`. It's not allocating an array at all.

It's the same as calling the constructor in a `new` expression for any other type:

```
std::string* s = new std::string("foo");
int* i = new int(10);
std::vector<std::string>* v = new std::vector<std::string>(5, "foo");
```

Answer (score 2):

`char t(a)` creates a local char initialized to the value of `a`.
`new char (a)` creates a dynamically allocated char initialized to the value of `a`.